# handling yyyy/mm/dd and yyyy-MMM-dd cases in java through regex or in simple way

Tags: java, regex, date

i have the below method signature in which there are two different parameters  out of which there is one parameter named dateStr, now inside dateStr variable there can be multiple date formats for example following are the values that can be inside dateStr variable

```
21/02/2014
05/25/2014
05/12/16
2016/12/26  (YYYY/MM-dd)   ****//check this pattern format  *******
2014-JAN-04 (YYYY-MMM-dd)   ****//check this pattern format ********
```

below is the method code signature

```
public java.util.Date extractDate(String dateStr, String dateType) {
}
```

now for the patterns like

(YYYY/MM-dd) and (YYYY-MMM-dd)  i have two handle these two patterns specially ignoring the rest other patterns so what i have come up with these if block

```
if (!dateStr.equals("YYYY-MM-dd" && "YYYY/MM-dd")) {
    // code
}
else
{
//***** handle YYYY-MM-dd && YYYY/MM-dd *** here 
}
```

please advise is it correct way or i can add any regex here also

Comment: `dateStr.equals("YYYY-MM-dd" && "YYYY/MM-dd")`?

Comment: @Satya for these two date formats i have to do something in my code but how could i check that the string value in the variable dateStr is  of YYYY-MM-dd or YYYY/MM-dd format

Comment: if(dateStr.equals(firstFormat) || dateStr.equals(secondFormat)){
//correct format
}

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan: *equals*?

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan i still not get it could you please show in code as I have done

Comment: sss, I'm not sure that he gets it either as this is not where you'd use a test for equality. You could create two SimpleDateFormat objects and try to parse with one, and if it throws an exception, try to parse with the second.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels completely agree with you please

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i am looking for more robust expression that is the regex one

Comment: Again, test with multiple SimpleDateFormat objects as outlined in duplicate. Don't use regex for this.

Comment: Thanks but a small request please can you show a little it in code as I have done that will help me to grasp ore

Comment: The duplicate will show you answers that have code with them.

Comment: There is no answer for yyyy-MM-dd format pls